# Removing zeros after a dash

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have data in a column formatted like:

```
012345-0001
001234-0011
123456-0111
000012-1234
```

i need a query to return the data like:

```
012345-1
001234-11
123456-111
000012-1234
```

i have created a function to remove a varying number of leading zeros, but can't figure out how to do it after the dash.

Thanks for any assistance

Function:

```
DECLARE @Output varchar(8000),  @Value int,  @Input varchar(8000)
    SELECT
       @Value = CASE
                  WHEN @Input LIKE '%[A-Z]%' THEN -1
                  ELSE CONVERT(int, RIGHT([matcode], 4))
                  END
      FROM  matter
      WHERE matcode = @Input
      IF (@Value = -1) SET @Output = @Input
      ELSE IF (@Value BETWEEN 1 AND 999) SET @Output = RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(varchar(3), @Value), 3)
      ELSE IF (@Value BETWEEN 1000 AND 9999) SET @Output = RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(varchar(4), @Value), 4)
      ELSE SET @Output = @Input
RETURN @Output
```

Comment: Show us your function

Comment: @matthewpage Added function

Comment: Is the value to the right of the dash always a valid integer? If so you can, as Mathew Page suggests, cast it as an integer and back to a string. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get the result.

```
select substr('001234-0011', 0, instr('001234-0011', '-') ) || 
replace(substr('001234-0011', instr('001234-0011', '-')+1), '0', '') from dual;
```

Use this if SqlServer as you have mentioned tSql

```
select substring('001234-0011', 0, CHARINDEX('-', '001234-0011')) + replace(substring('001234-0011', CHARINDEX('-', '001234-0011'), 10), '0', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but can't test it..

```
DECLARE @Output varchar(8000),  @Value int,  @Input varchar(8000)
SELECT
   @Value = CASE
      WHEN @Input LIKE '%[A-Z]%' THEN -1
      ELSE CONVERT(int, RIGHT([matcode], 4))
    END
  FROM  matter
  WHERE matcode = @Input
  IF (@Value = -1) SET @Output = @Input
  ELSE SET @Output = CONCAT( LEFT(@Input, 7), @Value )
RETURN @Output
```

Comment: To test SQL code for various DBMS i suggest using this: https://dbfiddle.uk/  also if you post the whole address you can pass a testable snippet: ex (with your code) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f7b998977815a63f541448c4b82ce8df

Answer (score 0):

The example below simply uses a `CASE` and a `LIKE` to check if the string ends with dash and 4 digits .

And a concat of an INT doesn't add leading zero's.

```
declare @Table table (col varchar(30));
insert into @Table (col) values
('012345-0001'),
('001234-0011'),
('123456-0111'),
('000012-1234');

select col as [in], 
(case 
 when col like '%-0[0-9][0-9][0-9]' 
 then concat(left(col,len(col)-4), cast(right(col,4) as int)) 
 else col 
 end) as [out]
from @Table;
```

*Returns:*

```
in          out
012345-0001 012345-1
001234-0011 001234-11
123456-0111 123456-111
000012-1234 000012-1234
```

A test [here](https://rextester.com/GSKKF74295)

Using the varchar variables it could be used like this:

```
DECLARE @Input varchar(30), @Output varchar(30);

SET @Input =  '012345-0001';

SET @Output = case when @Input like '%-0[0-9][0-9][0-9]' then concat(left(@Input,len(@Input)-4), cast(right(@Input,4) as int)) else @Input end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @var varchar(30)
set @var = '012345-0021'

select concat(
              left(@var,charindex('-',@var)-1), --keeps first side 'as is'
              '-', 
              right( --for the second part
                      right(@var,charindex('-',reverse(@var))),
                      charindex( '0', reverse(right(@var,4)) )-1 --finds the position first '0' of the reversed string (the last 0)
                    ) 
               ) as output
```

output: `012345-21`

Try it on db<>fiddle: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ca6789845e3290b6deca12a4b9fbc22a)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is use use parsename() with a concat

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,NewValue = concat( left(YourCol,charindex('-',YourCol+'-') ) 
                         ,try_convert(int,parseName(replace(YourCol,'-','.'),1))
                        )
 from YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
YourCol         NewValue
012345-0001     012345-1
001234-0011     001234-11
123456-0111     123456-111
000012-1234     000012-1234
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that most of the solutions assume that the each part of the text which is seems like a number, is on the length of 4 char.

Here is another solution Based on PARSENAME function which is a bit more flexible:

```
declare @Table table (col varchar(30));
insert into @Table (col) values
('012345-0001'),
('001234-0011'),
('123456-0111'),
('000012-1234')

SELECT 
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(col,'-','.'), 2) + 
    '-' + 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(REPLACE(col,'-','.'), 1)))
FROM @Table
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a *one-liner* using `XQuery`:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE (YourValue VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
('012345-0001'),
('001234-0011'),
('123456-0111'),
('000012-1234');
```

--This is the query

```
SELECT YourValue
      ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(YourValue,'-','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
           .value('concat(/x[1],"-",string(xs:int(/x[2])))','varchar(30)')
FROM @mockup;
```

The query will first transform your `012345-001` into `<x>012345</x><x>001</x>` with simple string replacements. The actual magic is happening within the `XQuery` expression.